# If two vector fields have same trajectory then they are topology equivalent.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

We have two smooth vector fields $X_1$ & $X_2$ in a smooth manifold $M$, the one variable differential homeomorphism group of them is denoted by $\phi_t$ & $\psi_t$ .

If they have same trajectory (that is for any $p\in$M   {$\phi_t(p)$} = {$\psi_t(p)$}   in the set category),can we find a differential self homeomorphism $h:M\rightarrow M$ (just need to be continuous),  satisfies $h\circ \phi_t\circ h^{-1}=\psi_t$ ?

What I have done is:

1. $M=\mathbb R$ (REAL LINE).
2. If we can fine a submanifold $N$ such that $N$ meet every trajectory in one and only one point(count multiplicity).

I'm not sure that this is correct.

Comment: Let me ask: Are you saying that you have proved that statement in the two special cases 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes, maybe I have not expressed clearly.

Comment: A related statement, used in Milnor's lectures on the h-cobordism theorem, p.57, without a proof, is that if two vector fields $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2}$ define the same trajectories and level sets (relative a Morse function on the manifold), then there is a positive function $k:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ with $v_1 = kv_2$.